# Modifying the Category.tpl in Opencart - or creating a duplicate that works dynamically

Tags: php, opencart

I am currently making an Opencart site. And I want to something a little different on it. Originally my plan for this was to hard-code it with just html and css - but then I thought I want to try and learn a tiny bit of how this could be done dynamically using the model view controller.

---

If you view the link to the photo below then look at the 8 grey boxes with a title and image inside:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/82026997@N04/7514113014/in/photostream

These are going to be the categories. I tried looking in model view and controller files to see if i could pull info like the category image into the category.tpl but I am really struggling as I'm still very green with it all.

Not only that, I only want this to be shown on the homepage and the categories to work as default so i figured editing the category tpl is the wrong thing to do as this would change the module throughout the site.

So in a nutsell I want the categories to work dynamically pulling the category name info and also the image info. (but only on the homepage)

Anybody got any solutions??? and also if you could just briefly explain why so I can understand it a little bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be easy for you. Go to your admin section and click extensions/modules click "install" on Category if it isn't installed yet. Next click "Edit".

Click "Add Module", choose layout Home, the position you want, choose "Enabled" for Status.
Click "Add Module", choose layout Category, the position you want, choose "Enabled" for Status.

**To add the image to the module:**

Edit catalog/controller/module/category.php

Where you see something like this:

```
$this->data['categories'][] = array(
    'category_id'       => $category['category_id'],
    'name'              => $category['name'],
    'children'          => $children_data,
    'href'              => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'])
);
```

Add the line for image:

```
$this->data['categories'][] = array(
    'category_id'       => $category['category_id'],
    'name'              => $category['name'],
    'image'             => $category['image'],
    'children'          => $children_data,
    'href'              => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'])
);
```

Then in view/*your_template*/module/category.tpl you can refer to it with (change width):

```
<img src="image/<?php echo $category['image']; ?>" title="<?php echo $category['name']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $category['name']; ?>" width="300"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for that but I was looking for a way to edit the actual category module with the php to show images along with title names.

I dont think I have worded the question quite clearly enough to be fair